# Install binutils on gentoo

Tags: installation, binutils, gentoo

How do i install binutils on gentoo? I have tried emerge but it gives an error saying

`-bash: emerge: command not found`

I tried install binutils but the syntax is :

```
Usage: install [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
```

Please help. I have tried a lot of other things which are probably not worth mentioning.

Also if there's a way around it.. I actually require the "strings" command which on ubuntu is present in binutils. Is there something else i should be trying?

Comment: `binutils` is part of the base system so you normally don't have to install it manually. `emerge` is also part of the base system and should be in `/usr/bin`. You can retry with `/usr/bin/emerge`. How did you install your Gentoo system ?

Comment: I have used an iso image for installation. Also /usr/bin/emerge doesnt work. Error says no such file/directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [If you wish to make an apple pie from scratch, you must first invent the universe.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7s664NsLeFM)

---

If emerge is not found, you have not installed Gentoo.

[How is the Installation Structured?](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-amd64.xml?part=1&chap=1)

- After step 1, you are in a working environment ready to install Gentoo
- After step 2, your internet connection is ready to install Gentoo
- After step 3, your hard disks are initialized to house your Gentoo installation
- After step 4, your installation environment is prepared and you are ready to chroot into the new environment
- After step 5, core packages, which are the same on all Gentoo installations, are installed
- After step 6, you have compiled your Linux kernel
- After step 7, you have written most of your Gentoo system configuration files
- After step 8, necessary system tools (which you can choose from a nice list) are installed
- After step 9, your choice of bootloader has been installed and configured and you are logged in into your new Gentoo installation
- After step 10, your Gentoo Linux environment is ready to be explored

---

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are attempting to emerge from the ISO itself, rather than inside your Gentoo chroot that you create using the ISO.

Check out the Gentoo Handbook for installation directions:
https://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/

Specifically the section entitled "6. Installing the Gentoo Base System". The link for this section in the AMD64 handbook is https://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-amd64.xml?full=1#book_part1_chap6

In short, you use the LiveCD to boot the machine, to partition your disk, and to create a chroot of Gentoo which becomes your full install. You emerge packages inside the chroot, and not from the LiveCD.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, the bash shell cannot find the emerge commands.  As mentioned by  Mickaël, you shouldn't need to emerge as it is included as part of stage3 tar balls.

Here are things to check.
a) check is the PATH variable. Check it include the usual suspect like '/usr/bin', '/bin', '/sbin'. and emerge is installed in one of them.
b) Check which method you used for your installation.  Is it the minimm .iso, the stage3 tar balls, or the 
livedvd.

See section 2.b. The Gentoo Installation in the handbook as mentioned.
And also read the section 5.c as it will tell you how to install the stage tarball, and it will include binutils in it.

c) Check your user permission, is your user refrain from called the emerge command?